# Cant overriding class when mapping with NHibernate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nhibernate, mapping, firebird

I have one class "MyClass" mapping with NHibernate but at my database table name  is upper case("MYCLASS"). I'm trying to make a integrated test, and when execute my test i got sql error ("Dynamic Sql Error"), i check the problem and my query is comming with double quotes at table name.

```
public class MyClass 
{
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual int NAME { get;  set; } 
}
```

How can i change NHibernate for dont use double quotes in table name query?

Comment: See the inner exception and paste the message here!

Comment: Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -204
Table unknown
Balancas
At line 1, column 178
That is inner execption, cause dont exist "Balancas" in my data base, if i try execute this query in my data base with out double quotes it run.
Ex: select * from "Balancas" -> dont run, cause name is upper case.
select * from Balancas -> it run!

Comment: And what mapping strategy are you using right now? Mapping by code?

Comment: Yes, i'm mapping by code.
    public class MapBalancas : ClassMap<Balancas>
    {
        public MapBalancas()
        {
            Id(c => c.CODI_BAL);
            Map(c => c.CODI_EMP);
            Map(c => c.DESC_BAL);
            Map(c => c.SITU_BAL);
            Map(c => c.DUMANUT);
        }
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, in mapping just have to add a property Table("TableName").

```
public class MapMyClass() : ClassMap<MyClass>
{
    public MapMyClass{
       Table("MYTABLE");
       Id(c => c.ID);
       Map(c => c.NAME);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was going to answer... and this is why I asked you about what mapping strategy you're currently using